# TLS verification issue when setting up remote docker interpreter in pycharm in Windows

Tags: windows, docker, pycharm

I try to use Docker integration in Pycharm in Windows 10.
It asks me to create a "Docker Server" (don't know what that is) and after I just use the default settings it tells me

> "Enabled TLS verification (DOCKER_TLS_VEROFY=1) but certificate path
>   (DOCKER_CERT_PATH) 'C:\xxx' doesn't exits"

. How do I fix that? Moreover, it seems like it tries to use "docker-machine" rather than the native "docker" cli. Why? (Again, I am new to docker so I am not sure what's the difference).

Answer (score 1):

> Since I had a failry hard time getting the remote interpreter running,
>   here is the short version for those using 64bit Windows 10 Pro,
>   Enterprise and Education (1511 November update, Build 10586 or later)
>   as specified here:
>   https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/#/docker-for-windows
>   And in the future hopefully all recent Windows 10 versions.
>
> There is no need to fiddle around with the docker-machine. When Docker
>   is up and running:
>   1. Make sure you share the C drive between Docker and your local machine
>   2. When specifying the remote interpreter set tcp://localhost:2375 as API URL. That’s it.

Credit: Markus at this blog post comments: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/#comment-296772